# cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I build UIView with few labels and one `UITableview`. the problem is that when I load the view the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
never get called. 
the code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  m_ShopSalesTable =[[UITableView alloc]init]; //this is the UITableView    
  m_ShopSalesTable.delegate = self; 
  m_ShopSalesTable.dataSource = self;   
  [self.view addSubview:m_ShopSalesTable];
  [m_ShopSalesTable reloadData];
}
```

i have put the `UITableViewDelegate` ,`UITableViewDataSource`> in the declaration of the class
but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing with no frame. You are doing this:

```
[[UITableView alloc]init];
```

I would do this:

```
[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, *setYourWidthHere*, *setYourHeightHere*)];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where cellForRowAtIndexPath was never called.
I had several issues:

- my tableView was not connected in my .xib file
- the data I was filling came from an http delegate callback,
  so I had to use performSelectorOnMainThread()
- lastly, I was using grouped views, so my mistake was that
  I did not add a section to my table.

Spent about 5 hours trying to figure this out, hope it helps
someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the tableView datasource to be the class that implements the above method? Did you return a non-zero number for both -numberOfSectionsInTableView: and –tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:? Are ANY of your tableview datasource methods being called?

Comment: yes the method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [m_CurrShop.m_SalesList count];
}
get called and return 3.

Comment: And the numberOfSectionsInTable: returns what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you assign tableview to m_shopSales Try:

```
self.tableView=m_ShopSalesTable;
```

before `reloadData`

Also m_ShopSalesTable is leaking do a release after setting self.tableView.

Answer (score 0):

As Kalle has asked in a comment on another answer, what are you returning from your numberOfSections method? In the default created from the template, I think this returns zero which has bitten me on a few occasions.